# How to parametrize a test with several pytest markers?

Tags: python, pytest

Say that I want to run the same test code with several pytest markers. One solution is to copy-paste the test with the markers applied:

```
@pytest.mark.A
def test_a():
    # same
    # code
    ...

@pytest.mark.B
def test_b():
    # same
    # code
    ...
```

One "hack" I found is to parametrize a dummy parameter and apply different markers using `pytest.param`:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("_", [
    pytest.param(None, marks=pytest.mark.A),
    pytest.param(None, marks=pytest.mark.B),
])
def test(_):
    # same
    # code
    ...
```

But it is clumsy and adds unused parameters. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Do you mean you want to trigger `test` once and it will run twice or you want the test to run when you run tests with `A` marker or `B` marker?

Comment: I want to run the test twice, one with each marker. If I select tests only with marker `A`, then run only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that yields `pytest.param` and use a fake name (an empty string) in `parametrize` to avoid sending a parameter to the test

```
def add_markers():
    for mark in [pytest.mark.A, pytest.mark.B]:
        yield pytest.param(marks=mark)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('', add_markers())
def test_example():
    # code
```

Comment: I get an error: "the number of names (0) must be equal to the number of values (1)"

Comment: @astrojuanlu Did you change anything?

Comment: Weird, turning it into a simple case made it work again. I'll look into my actual code once more.

Comment: Works! I was making a mistake somewhere else. Thanks!